# How to remove spaces in customized Title bar

Tags: android, android-titlebar

Description : I am creating customized title bar. The codes for customization is as follow :

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dp</item>
     </style>
</resources>
```

title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/customtitlecolor" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/about_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9px"
        android:layout_marginTop="6px"
        android:background="@drawable/custombuttoncolor"
        android:paddingBottom="8px"
        android:paddingLeft="8px"
        android:paddingRight="8px"
        android:paddingTop="8px"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>

and finally 

customizedtitlecolor.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <gradient android:startColor="#000000" android:endColor="#777777" android:angle="90"/>
     <corners android:radius="7dp"/>
    </shape>
```

code in my main activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
```

Question: My customized title is not adopting fill parent width. There are grey spaces at right and left side. how to remove these spaces??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it this way it will be solved :

your style XML:

```
<resources> 
 <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground" /> 
 <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme"> 
 <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dp</item>
 <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground
 </item>
 </style> </resources>>
```

then refer it in manifest as :

```
 android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Hope this help .

Comment: Thanks alot for solving my problem. It was really very helpful.